# Java Exercise: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and all help is appreciated

Tags: java, class, methods

I am working with the following pieces of code and I keep getting this error message: *Error: Main method not found in class Team, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args) or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application*. All suggestions, opinions, and changes are welcome as I am completely lost on why this isn't working. Thanks so much in advance and I hope you all have a great day!

```
Game.java:

public class Game {

  private Team team1;
  private Team team2;
  private String time;

  public Game(Team t1, Team t2, String time) {
    super();

    this.team1 = team1;
    this.team2 = team2;
    this.time = time;
  }

  public String getTime() {
    return "TIME";
  }

}


Team.java:

public class Team {

  private String name;
  private String sport;
  private String mascot;
  public final static String MOTTO = "Sportsmanship!";

  public Team(String name, String sport, String mascot) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sport = sport;
    this.mascot = mascot;
  }

  //method to set the school name
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  //method to set the sport name
  public String getSport() {
    return sport;
  }

  //method to set the team name
  public String getMascot() {
    return mascot;
  }
}


TestGame.java:

public class TestGame {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Team team1 = new Team("Roosevelt High", "Girls Basketball", "Dolphins");
    Team team2 = new Team("Hoover High", "Girls Basketball", "Tigers");
    Game game1 = new Game(team1, team2, "7 PM");

    System.out.println("The game between " + team1.getName() + " " + team1.getSport() +
        " " + team1.getMascot());
    System.out.println("   and " + team2.getName() + " " + team2.getSport() +
        " " + team2.getMascot());
    System.out.println("   takes place at " + game1.getTime());
  }
}


TestTeam.java:

public class TestTeam {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Team team1 = new Team("Roosevelt High", "Girls Basketball", "Dolphins");
    Team team2 = new Team("Hoover High", "Boys Wrestling", "Tigers");
    Team team3 = new Team("Lincoln High", "Girls Field Hockey", "Gators");
    display(team1);
    display(team2);
    display(team3);
  }

  public static void display(Team team) {
    System.out.println(
        team.getName() + "" + team.getSport() + "" + team.getMascot() + ""
            + Team.MOTTO);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your Game.java class is incomplete, it doesn't have `getTime` method. Also there are missed some curly brackets. Complete it please.
2. Also your TestGame class has not `t1`, `t2` and `g` variables. It has `team1`, `team2` and `game` instead. Fix this too.
3. You have an error inside your `display` method. You pass here only one `Team t`, but inside this method you're trying to print data from some `team1`, `team2`, `team3` variables. They just doesn't exists in that scope.
4. Inside the display method you're trying to get static class variable vie instance. There is no sence in that.

Here is an example of working code.

Game.java:

```
public class Game {

  private Team team1;
  private Team team2;
  private String time;

  public Game(Team t1, Team t2, String time) {
    super();

    this.team1 = team1;
    this.team2 = team2;
    this.time = time;
  }

  public String getTime() {
    return "TIME";
  }

}
```

Team.java:

```
public class Team {

  private String name;
  private String sport;
  private String mascot;
  public final static String MOTTO = "Sportsmanship!";

  public Team(String name, String sport, String mascot) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sport = sport;
    this.mascot = mascot;
  }

  //method to set the school name
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  //method to set the sport name
  public String getSport() {
    return sport;
  }

  //method to set the team name
  public String getMascot() {
    return mascot;
  }
}
```

TestGame.java:

```
public class TestGame {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Team team1 = new Team("Roosevelt High", "Girls Basketball", "Dolphins");
    Team team2 = new Team("Hoover High", "Girls Basketball", "Tigers");
    Game game1 = new Game(team1, team2, "7 PM");

    System.out.println("The game between " + team1.getName() + " " + team1.getSport() +
        " " + team1.getMascot());
    System.out.println("   and " + team2.getName() + " " + team2.getSport() +
        " " + team2.getMascot());
    System.out.println("   takes place at " + game1.getTime());
  }
}
```

TestTeam.java:

```
public class TestTeam {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Team team1 = new Team("Roosevelt High", "Girls Basketball", "Dolphins");
    Team team2 = new Team("Hoover High", "Boys Wrestling", "Tigers");
    Team team3 = new Team("Lincoln High", "Girls Field Hockey", "Gators");
    display(team1);
    display(team2);
    display(team3);
  }

  public static void display(Team team) {
    System.out.println(
        team.getName() + "" + team.getSport() + "" + team.getMascot() + ""
            + Team.MOTTO);
  }
}
```

Comment: What are the errors? I've tested all of that. It works well.

Comment: Error: Main method not found in class Team, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args) or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Comment: `Team` class is not your main class. You need to run classes with `public static void main` methods to run your application. You have two of them: `TestTeam` or `TestGame`. Run any of these.

Comment: I'm running them and they display the correct output however on Cengage, it's telling  me that the Tam class is not functioning as requested still. Below are the contents that it is testing.

Comment: @Test
public void unitTest() {
    Team team = new Team ("Lincoln High", "Girls Field Hockey", "Gators");
    assertEquals(team.getName(), "Lincoln High");
    assertEquals(team.getSport(), "Girls Field Hockey");
    assertEquals(team.getMascot(), "Gators");
    Team team2 = new Team("Essex High", "Golf", "Hornets");
    assertEquals(team2.getName(), "Essex High");
    assertEquals(team2.getSport(), "Golf");
    assertEquals(team2.getMascot(), "Hornets");
}

Comment: And what is wrong here? Do you have any errors or something except this random pieces of code? What I can answer on that?

Comment: No I guess not. Other than it just telling me that the main methods are not found like I stated above. I'm  not sure what is wrong or how to fix it. I do appreciate all of your help though I brought my assignment grade to a 33 instead of a 0 so that's much better!

Comment: You are calling some methods inside your unit tests which ARE NOT EXISTS. That's the problem. Implement them in your `Team` class. And it will work. Feel free to upvote my answer then if it was helpful for you.

Comment: I tried to upvote your answer already and it display a message stating "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

 Also, I'm not sure how to implement them into my Team class. I'm very new to Java and this is only my fourth program so I'm limited to what I really know how to do and am trying to learn. Again. I appreciate all of your help.. Have a great day.

Comment: @Kay, I've updated my answer. Your strange unit test should work now. If it was helpful you can mark question as accepted.

Comment: I'm sorry my question is terrible I'm new to all of this and the only thing I knew to do was to post it here were professionals such as yourself could help me work through the issues. I have marked your answers as accepted as they helped me tremendously. Your updates worked and hopefully the next time I need help I can format my question better. Again, Thank you for all of your time and help. Have a great day!

Comment: You are welcome. I can recommend you to show more problem related details. Your unit test were a surprise for me. You need to look carefully into this. Good luck to you!